# portrait picture in a image gallery

Tags: php, css, resolution

I have an image gallery i want to use portrait images but every portrait picture gets stretched.

I want to know how exactly can i set a fixed resolution and all picture are aligned automatically.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is impossible to answer without seeing some details, maybe some code.

Comment: More detail needed. Is this a PHP problem or an HTML/CSS problem? Example code would be good.

Comment: -1 for not providing any meaningful detail even after having been asked repeatedly.

Comment: thanks for replying guys, i'm sorry didn't update my question caz i got busy with work. i understood what needs to be done. I only set the 'width' and let 'height' be auto and realized that's the max i could do since it was a dynamic gallery with a lot of interaction with the database. thanks and apologize again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the width of each picture in hthml:

```
<img src="folder/image.jpg" width="500" height="500" />
```

It is recommended by W3C to apply height and width attributes to each inline `img` tag!

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried this, doesn't solve the problem. Can't we put a javascript/css property that will put [this image] (http://www.motorbeam.com/wp-content/uploads/Toyota_Corolla_Altis_Diesel.jpg) in 500/500 resolution w/o shrinking it?

Comment: Each image has an [Aspect Ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio)o which you should not touch. By just setting the width you want for the picture in ratio in CSS, the image will be scaled down and the aspect ratio will remain: `img{width: 500px;}`!